# nodejs chatroom object expected line one

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using this [tutorial](http://www.williammora.com/2013/03/nodejs-tutorial-building-chatroom-with.html) to try to learn how to make a chatroom with nodejs.

I got down to where it shows the page with a button and text area, but then when I ran it, it gave an object expected microsoft javascript error on line one, which remained the same as before.

```
var express = require("express");
```

And while i'm here I might as well ask... is the following code:

```
  var express = require("express")
     , app = express()
     , http = require("http").createServer(app);
```

the same as this code:

```
var express = require("express");
app = express();
http = require("http").createServer(app);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.JS won't give you a Microsoft JavaScript error. I'm guessing you're trying to run your script under Windows Script Host, which won't work. You need to download Node.JS and run it under that.

From your comment, you note that you're running your script from the Windows Command Prompt:

```
D:\> chat.js
```

That will open it with the default document viewer, which just happens to be Windows Script Host here. To run it with Node.JS, you need to explicitly add `node`:

```
D:\> node chat.js
```

As for the second question, no, but almost. You can declare multiple variables in one line, e.g.:

```
var a, b, c;
```

You can also initialize them all:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

This is not the same thing as

```
var a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
```

Using commas makes them part of the `var` statement and create a new variable. Without the `var`, it will use a previously-declared variable or, worse, put it in the global scope.

Comment: I thought I was typing node, but apparently I wasn't. odd. Also about the second question?

Comment: @user1743752: I've updated my answer to answer both questions.